# How to iterate over Yii CActiveDataProvider object?

Tags: php, mysql, html, yii

How to iterate over a dataprovider object? I want to access the 'name' field of each row returned and build a list. Can you help?

**Table structure for table/model `categories`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `idCategory` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCategory`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=55 ;
```

****Function in my Controller Categories****

```
    $names = array();
    public function returnCategoryNames()
{
    $dataProvider= new CActiveDataProvider('Categories');
    $dataProvider->setPagination(false);
    $count = $dataProvider->totalItemCount();

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){

             // this is where I am lost...
             $myname = $dataProvider->data[$i]->name;
             array_push($names, $myname);

    }   

       return $names;

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function returnCategoryNames()
{
  $dataProvider= new CActiveDataProvider('Categories');
  $dataProvider->setPagination(false);
  //$count = $dataProvider->totalItemCount();
  $names = array();
  foreach($dataProvider->getData() as $record) {
    $names[] = $record->name;
  }
  return array_unique($names);
}
```

However you dont need to use a data provider, instead just use the model

```
foreach(Categories::model()->findAll() as $record) {
```

Comment: I really like the second option you gave (Categories::model()). Is there a way to do ORDER BY with this option? or is that askin too much

Comment: easy: `Categories::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'name'));`, you can find details on the find() commands at: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail

Answer (score 14):

If you need itarate large data collection and you worry about memory usage do this:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Categories');
$iterator = new CDataProviderIterator($dataProvider);
foreach($iterator as $category) {
   print_r($category);
}
```

CDataProviderIterator allows iteration over large data sets without holding the entire set in memory.

some performance tests

```
Test                        Time (seconds)          Memory (bytes)
CDbDataReader               4.9158580303192         28339952
CActiveRecord::findAll()    5.8891110420227         321388376
CDataProviderIterator       6.101970911026          31170504
```

Comment: CDataProvider will still call findAll(), it just allows you to specify the number of times you want to make an actual sql query by paging. CDbDataReader only makes 1 sql call and iterate over the results in a memory efficient manner.

Comment: CDataProviderIterator is NOT the same as CDataProvider

Answer (score 5):

In Yii2 this has changed too:

```
    $searchModel = new ModelSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    foreach($dataProvider->getModels() as $record) {
        echo $record->id . '<br>';
    }

    exit();
```

Reference: [getModels()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html#getModels%28%29-detail)

Answer (score 4):

With the solution of @ben-rowe you are querying all the rows at once. You can have memory issues.

With the following solution you will fetch the categories from ten by ten (the default [`CPagination.pageSize`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#getPageSize-detail) value):

```
        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Categories', array(
            'pagination' => array(
                'validateCurrentPage' => false
            ),
        ));
        $pagination = $dataProvider->pagination;
        while ($categories = $dataProvider->getData(true)){
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                //...
            }
            $pagination->currentPage++;
        }
```

Comment: thanx for this solution!