# Yii Search for a custom defined field

Tags: php, yii

I have to look up names as a combination of first name and last name i.e concat of fname & lname and return all the possible matches. Now I have been able to have a good amount of success in doing that by looking [into this post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12090-filter-by-concatenation-of-model-fields-in-cgridview/).

Now I have my model class where I search for the student name like this:

```
class StudentRegistration extends CActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * Public Varibale that defines the full name 
     */

     public $full_name;


     //my search function has something like this
     public function search()
     {
          $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
          $criteria->addSearchCondition('concat(fname, " ", lname)', $this->full_name); 
     .
     .
     .

     //my rules defining this
     full_name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),

    //my getter method like this
    public function getFull_Name()
    {
            return $this->fld_fname.' '.$this->fld_lname;
    }

}
```

With this structure I have been able to add a full name attribute to my view and been able to search the full name in my form view.

Now here is the part where I am completely stumped. I am trying to access this search criteria I have defined to search for the full name in an ajax function in another view with a different model.

There I have defined a variable for the name field and have a controller assigned to return the search results from the studentReg model search. But I am having no success (my netbeans/xdebug unceremoniously crashes if I put breakpoints complaining about watches being present, when I have none)

Here is my search action class

```
  class StudentRegChecklistController extends Controller
  {
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
        public function actionSearchStudent()
        {
        if(Yii::app()->request->getIsAjaxRequest() && isset($_POST["autoField"]))
        {
            $models=  StudentSearch::searchStudent($_POST["autoField"]);                
            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->compare("full_name",$_POST["autoField"],true);
            $models=  StudentRegistration::model()->findAll($criteria);
            foreach($models as $model)
            {
              echo "<option value=$model->gno style=\"font-size:18px;cursor:pointer\">".$model->fname." ".$model->lname."</option>";
              echo "</br>";
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong in the controller? Trying to achieve something [like this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/39111-where-to-write-jqueryajax-code-in-custom-autocomplete-text-field/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using `StudentRegistration::model()->findAll($criteria)` instead of `StudentRegistration::model()->search()`

The first method will look at your model table using the *$criteria* information and will try to match the relevant table columns. But *full_name* is not a table column.

The *search()* method uses *$this* as a filter. *$this* is a **StudentRegistration** instance, *$this->full_name* is a known attribute and *search()* knows how to handle it.

If you want to add more filters, just set the relevant attributes in the instance you use as a filter. Something like :

```
$filter = new StudentRegistration();
$filter->setAttributes(array('full_name' => "John Doe", 'registration_date' => '2013-01-01'));
$results = $filter->search();
```

**NB :** Instead of *setAttributes()*, you may want to use the massive assignment handled by the CActiveRecord, provided all your inputs are 'safe for search' :

```
$filter->attributes = $my_array_of_parameters; // likely $_POST['something']
```

If they are not 'safe for search', set the second argument of setAttributes() to false. 
Or use *setAttribute()*...

Comment: So, I think I understand what you are trying to say. I basically need to use a `attribute search query` which is inbuilt in yii instead of what I am currently doing which is basically a sql query of sorts? [I have rewritten the function](http://pastebin.com/GJuuevuA) based on my understanding but unfortunately even this is throwing errors =/

Comment: @Shouvik: I have tested a similar code in one of my projects and it works. At least I've got the data after the call to search(). What are the errors thrown ?

Comment: I have attached a pastebin to the comment. http://pastebin.com/GJuuevuA Can you check if the definition of the function is incorrect?

Comment: I'm using NetBEans + xdebug also. Anyway, if you've errors thrown, they must show somewhere in the logs or in your browser. Please tell us more about the error messages. What is the content of $_POST['autoField'] ? Is your error about parsing the results ? Then also check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170102/how-to-iterate-over-yii-cactivedataprovider-object. Hard to tell more without details ;o)

Comment: :) I am at a loss too! Actually I prefer to google if I see error messages. I am able to see the result of the post back, it's a partial name, I am using jquery postback. My browser says server responded with 500 internal error, my debugging logs i don't know where to look. But the Apache logs are here http://pastebin.com/QrRC7uNS

Comment: Let me work with the iteration of the return value. I think that's where my error lies.. Will get back once I can manage to break through. thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Btw, is the function written here correct? http://pastebin.com/GJuuevuA because I think the function might be wrongly iterating through the return values.. =/

Comment: Okay, so I finally managed to trace the error message! It's `Trying to get property of non-object` which occurs on this line `echo "<option value=$model->gno style=\"font-size:18px;cursor:pointer\">".$model->fname." ".$model->lname."</option>"`

Comment: How are you iterating the results ? Show us the code and maybe we could help. Anyway, IMHO, this question should be moved in another thread. It's not related to the search of a custom field.